# Firebase Auth, Logged out on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

**Technologies:** I'm using Firebase Auth with NextJS & React.

**Problematic:** Logged users can use the web app with firebase auth normally only if they navigate within the app via Next routing, whenever they refresh the page or open a new account tab they are not logged in anymore.

**Issue:** It is extremely frustrating because this problem only occurs on production. There's no problem at all on the staging & localhost environment.

---

**firebase.js**: Initialize firebase.

```
import getConfig from "next/config";
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

export async function initializeFirebase() {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(JSON.parse(publicRuntimeConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG));

        if (publicRuntimeConfig.FIREBASE_ANALYTICS) {
            firebase.analytics();
        }
    }
}

export const auth = firebase.auth
export const db = firebase.firestore;
export default firebase;
```

**AuthHoC.js**: To make sure the user is connected I wrapper my pages with a HOC.

```
export default App => (
    class AuthHoC extends App {
        _isMounted = false;

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = { 
                loading: false,
                isVerified: false,
                idToken: undefined,
                isAuthenticated: false
            }
        }


        async componentDidMount() {
            this._isMounted = true;
            await initializeFirebase();
            // onAuthStateChanged return a function that we'll use to unsubscribe our listener
            this.unsubscribeMethod = await auth().onAuthStateChanged(this._handleStateChange);
        }

        // is user is null, we're no longer authenticated
        _handleStateChange = (user) => {
            let that = this;
            if (user) {
                // NOT PASSING HERE ON PAGE REFRESH...
                user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) { 
                    that.setState({
                        loading: true,
                        idToken: idToken,
                        isVerified: user.emailVerified,
                        isAuthenticated: !!user
                    });
                });
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            if (this.unsubscribeMethod) {
                this.unsubscribeMethod();
            }

            this._isMounted = false;
        }

        render() {
            return ( <>
                {this.state.loading ? 
                    <App {...this.props} {...this.state} /> 
                : 
                    ... loading ...
                }
            </> )
        }
});
```

**_app.js**: (NextJS) Wrap every pages with the Higher Order Component.

```
import App from "next/app";
import AuthHoC from '../utils/authentication/authHoC';

class MyApp extends App {
    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps, isAuthenticated, idToken, isVerified } = this.props;

        return (
            <Component 
                {...pageProps} 
                isAuth={isAuthenticated}
                idToken={idToken}  
                isVerified={isVerified}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default AuthHoC(MyApp);
```

What could be the issue? All these codes work on localhost & staging url, just not on production.

---

**EDIT:**

I pinpointed the problem, I just switched my production keys with staging and it works, that means that the problem is not coming from the Heroku or my code but my Firebase configuration itself.

The main difference is that the prod use analytics. If you have any info I forgot to configure any suggestion would help.